# Lambda expressions with CUDA

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, cuda

If I use `thrust::transform` on `thrust::host`, the lambda usage is fine

```
thrust::transform(thrust::host, a, a+arraySize,b,d,[](int a, int b)->int
{
    return a + b;
});
```

However, if I change `thrust::host` to `thrust::device`, the code wouldn't pass the compiler. Here is the error on VS2013:

> The closure type for a lambda ("lambda [](int, int)->int") cannot be used in the template argument type of a `__global__` function template instantiation, unless the lambda is defined within a `__device__` or `__global__` function

So, the problem is how using `__device__` or `__global__` in connection to device lambdas.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to add the `__device__` before the lambda definition, then the compiler would complain `error : expected an expression`. Any ideas ?

Comment: I am going to guess that *if* this can be made to work (and I don't know whether that is the case or note), you would need to define the lamba at global scope and decorate it with `__device__ __host__`, maybe something like `__device__ __host__ auto cudalambda = [](int a, int b)->int { return a + b;};` then use it in the thrust closure, But that is just a wild guess

Comment: I have tried it. Same error message in my post.

Comment: OK so the answer is probably that you can't do it. Write a functor instead

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In CUDA 7 it is not possible.  Quoting from [Mark Harris](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/hruGCUrnHtk):

> That isn't supported today in CUDA, because the lambda is host code. Passing lambdas from host to device is a challenging problem, but it is something we will investigate for a future CUDA release.
>
> What you *can* do in CUDA 7 is call thrust algorithms from your device code, and in that case you can pass lambdas to them...

With CUDA 7, thrust algorithms can be called from device code (e.g. CUDA kernels, or `__device__` functors).  In those situations, you can use (device) lambdas with thrust.  An example is given in the parallelforall blog post  [here](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/power-cpp11-cuda-7/).

However, CUDA 7.5 introduces an experimental device lambda feature.  This feature is described [here](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/new-features-cuda-7-5/):

> CUDA 7.5 introduces an experimental feature: GPU lambdas. GPU lambdas are anonymous device function objects that you can define in host code, by annotating them with a `__device__` specifier.

In order to enable compilation for this feature, (currently, with CUDA 7.5) it's necessary to specify `--expt-extended-lambda` on the `nvcc` compile command line.

Comment: Thanks, I tried whole day to figure it out but in vain. So I use a Functor warpper instead.

Comment: With CUDA 7.5 one can declare device lambdas in host code with `[] __device__ (params...) { code ... }` plus passing to `nvcc` this flag: `--expt-extended-lambda`

Answer (score 9):

This simple code using device lambdas work under CUDA 8.0 RC, although device lambdas for this version of CUDA are still at an experimental stage:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(void)
{
    // --- Input data 
    float a = 2.0f;
    float x[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float y[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    thrust::device_vector<float> X(x, x + 4);
    thrust::device_vector<float> Y(y, y + 4);

    thrust::transform(X.begin(), 
                      X.end(),  
                      Y.begin(), 
                      Y.begin(),
                      [=] __host__ __device__ (float x, float y) { return a * x + y; }      // --- Lambda expression 
                     );        

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) std::cout << a << " * " << x[i] << " + " << y[i] << " = " << Y[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Remember to use

```
--expt-extended-lambda
```

for compilation.

Comment: It looks like they still require `--expt-extended-lambda` even at CUDA 10.1 (in 2019)

Comment: Yes, I wish they would get rid of the flag. By the way, it's now spelled: `--extended-lambda`.