# CUDA Thrust shortcut math functions

Tags: lambda, cuda, placeholder, functor, thrust

Is there a way to automatically wrap a CUDA math function in a functor so that one can apply `thrust::transform` without having to write a functor manually?  Something like the functionality that (I gather) `std::function` provides?

`thrust::placeholders` doesn't seem to like math functions.
`std::function` doesn't seem to be available.

Example code:

```
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <math.h>

struct myfunc{
    __device__ 
    double operator()(double x,double y){
    return hypot(x,y);
    }
};

int main(){

    double x0[10] = {3.,0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.};
    double y0[10] = {4.,0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.};

    thrust::device_vector<double> x(x0,x0+10);
    thrust::device_vector<double> y(y0,y0+10);
    thrust::device_vector<double> r(10);

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) std::cout << x0[i] <<" ";    std::cout<<std::endl;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) std::cout << y0[i] <<" ";    std::cout<<std::endl;

    // this works:
    thrust::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),r.begin(), myfunc());

    // this doesn't compile:
    using namespace thrust::placeholders;
    thrust::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),r.begin(), hypot(_1,_2));

    // nor does this:
    thrust::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),r.begin(), std::function<double(double,double)>(hypot));


    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) std::cout << r[i] <<" ";    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There's no automatic way to do it. One way to achieve something like this might be to make something like [`std::bind` that interoperated with CUDA](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/thrust_bind).Then you would need to define overloads of all the math functions of interest (e.g. `hypot`) in terms of `bind`.

Comment: in CUDA 7.5 you could use the [experimental `--expt-extended-lambda` feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30441692/678093) and write `auto h = [] __device__(double x, double y){return hypot(x,y);}; thrust::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),r.begin(), h);`

Comment: @m.s. if you want to provide an answer I would upvote.  I don't think Jared will object.

Answer (score 3):

*Converting my comment into this answer:*

As @JaredHoberock already stated, there is no automatic way to achieve what you want. There is always some syntactic / typing overhead.

One way to reduce this overhead of writing a separate functor (as you did with `my_func`) is to use lambdas. Since CUDA 7.5 there is an [experimental device lambda feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438538/does-cuda-7-fully-support-lambda-on-device-code/30441692#30441692) which allows you to do the folllowing:

```
auto h = []__device__(double x, double y){return hypot(x,y);};
thrust::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),r.begin(), h);
```

You need to add the following nvcc compiler switch to compile this:

```
nvcc --expt-extended-lambda ...
```

---

Another approach is to convert the function into a functor using the following `Wrapper`:

```
template<typename Sig, Sig& S>
struct Wrapper;

template<typename R, typename... T, R(&function)(T...)>
struct Wrapper<R(T...), function>
{
    __device__
    R operator() (T&... a)
    {
        return function(a...);
    }
};
```

You would then use it like this:

```
 thrust::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),r.begin(), Wrapper<double(double,double), hypot>());
```

Answer (score 1):

As remarked by m.s., a possible way to reduce the overhead of writing a functor is to use **lambda expressions**. Please, note that GPU lambdas are available with CUDA 8.0 RC (although still at an experimental stage). Another possibility is using the **placeholders** technique. Below, there are two working examples for the two mentioned cases:

**LAMBDA EXPRESSIONS**

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

// Available for device operations only from CUDA 8.0 (experimental stage)
// Compile with the flag --expt-extended-lambda

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(void)
{
    // --- Input data 
    float a = 2.0f;
    float x[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float y[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    thrust::device_vector<float> X(x, x + 4);
    thrust::device_vector<float> Y(y, y + 4);

    thrust::transform(X.begin(), 
                      X.end(),  
                      Y.begin(), 
                      Y.begin(),
                      [=] __host__ __device__ (float x, float y) { return a * x + y; }      // --- Lambda expression 
                     );        

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) std::cout << a << " * " << x[i] << " + " << y[i] << " = " << Y[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**PLACEHOLDERS**

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(void)
{
    // --- Input data 
    float a = 2.0f;
    float x[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float y[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    thrust::host_vector<float> X(x, x + 4);
    thrust::host_vector<float> Y(y, y + 4);

    thrust::transform(X.begin(), X.end(),
                      Y.begin(),         
                      Y.begin(),
                      a * _1 + _2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) std::cout << a << " * " << x[i] << " + " << y[i] << " = " << Y[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```